# React and Laravel: Stylesheet Violates Content Security Policy Directive

Tags: reactjs, laravel, content-security-policy

I have an application with React frontend and Laravel api. I have deployed the application to a Ubuntu server 19.04 installed with Nginx web server. I have added the following Content-Security-Policy header:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-xt0Buo5Rzgu1TLgyTQL5D5rCmE6u3GkzB+oPsldMDQc=' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com ; img-src 'self' data:;";
```

When I try to open the application, it fails with the console displaying the following error messages:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'"

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-xt0Buo5Rzgu1TLgyTQL5D5rCmE6u3GkzB+oPsldMDQc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

Opening the browser **Network** tab, I observe  two response content-security-policy headers. The first header is the one I added to the web server but I cannot figure out where the second header is coming from.

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-xt0Buo5Rzgu1TLgyTQL5D5rCmE6u3GkzB+oPsldMDQc=' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com ; img-src 'self' data:;

content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self';
```

I have reloaded the web server, reboot the server and tried clearing all caches but I can't find a way of removing it.

Would appreciate any help in resolving the errors or a way to remove the second content-security-policy header.